# Publishing private code to OpenShift

Tags: git, openshift

I don't have any technical problems publishing a python wsgi app using OpenShift. My concern is that they generate a Git repo for you to use, and you have to push to that repo in order to publish your code. Private Git repos cost money, so I assume the repo they generate is public.  Making this code public is not an option as it could someday be proprietary. I really like OpenShift and want to use it for this project. **Does anyone know of a way to publish using OpenShift but still keep the code private?**

Note: I'm NOT looking for a way to keep a private Git repo synced with OpenShift's Git repo. I am looking for a way to prevent other people from looking at OpenShift's Git repo and seeing my source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. According to the [OpenShift documentation](https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications):

> Every OpenShift application you create has its own Git repository that only you can access.

Answer (score 2):

The git repository for your application is private, protected by SELinux and SSH public/private key authentication.  It is not shared with anyone unless you choose to share it with them.