# Is the Heroku Git Repo Public?

Tags: git, heroku

When deploying an app, Heroku's [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#deploy-the-app) mentions a `git push`. Does this mean that Heroku pushes my code to a public Git repo? Or is it private, like [OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318038/publishing-private-code-to-openshift)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You push into a private git.heroku.com repo that yourself and your app collaborators have access to.

That is what [HTTP Git authentication](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication) says:

> **The Heroku HTTP Git endpoint only accepts API-key based HTTP Basic authentication by default and SSH is also supported using keys.**
>   (A username is not required and any value passed for username is ignored and SSH keys for SSH.)

Meaning: if there is no authentication, no git endpoint operation is possible (including cloning/pulling with anonymous access).
That makes all heroku git repo private.

Comment: Do you have any link to an heroku documentation *clearly* stating that?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication - try and clone a repo you don't have access to and you'll get an access denied.

Comment: That is about authentication. I don't see anything that says: anonymous access (read/clone) is not possible.

Comment: yeah, you need to be authenticated. Feel free to try and clone one of my apps - `git clone https://git.heroku.com/jb-geocode.git`

Answer (score 18):

No, the code is not public. Do not confuse GIT with GITHUB.

[When you deploy to heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code) the repository is private to the owner and the added [collaborators](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/collab).

Comment: ok, none can see the code... how about the website? who can check the website I deploy? is it visible to everyone or only me and my collaborators can see it?

Comment: @youHaveAlsoBeenABeginner the website is public, everyone who has the URL can visit it, unless you deploy to a private space https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces

Answer (score 1):

You Don't have to worry about that because in the Heroku platform the git we use for deployment was private. You could do pull/clone/push to your git to the Heroku because you might provide the SSH key of your computer to your Heroku account. So, if anyone tries to clone/pull/push to your Heroku git, he will fail to do that. Note: if your SSH key is licked with others, he can access your git and do anything with your Heroku git.